# Passing values from ajax to php class functions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Q. Is there a way to pass values from ajax to a certain php class having functions? Let's say validating a username on the registration form whether the user exist or not.

This is a simple form that will accept username and has a span tag to display the message.

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="username"><span class="check"></span>
  <input type="submit" name="signup">
</form>
```

And for the php class:

```html
<?php 
  class User {
    function isUserExist($username) {
      $query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
      $result = mysql_num_rows($query);

      return ($result !== 0 ? true : false);
    }
  }
?>
```

It is initialized on the php class that established connection to the database.
So calling to the php page will become like this: $user->isUserExist($_POST['username']);.

So is it possible to pass values from the form to ajax and send it to the php class function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From Html to ajax*

```
var username = $("input[name='username']").value;
```

*Fetch in ajax & Send it to php(server)*

```
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      //set your span to this -> xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "your php script url", true);
  xhttp.send("username="+username);
```

*Receive it on the server(php)*

```
$mUsername = $_POST['username'];
echo $mUsername;
```

*Read this tutorial for more help*
[Tutorial on PHP + AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_php.asp)

Comment: Can you give me some explanation with this? I'm still quite new about ajax.

Comment: read about it on w3schools. Pretty simple and neat explanation. What are we doing here is : We create a request XmlHttpRequest , wait for a change in that change status (readyState == 200 means good to go). then we put params and send it using send method.

Comment: I've tried it. But how to call the function inside the class? I declare the `$username = $_POST['username'];` before the class to make it global but it says that the username is undefined.

Comment: Function `isUserExist($username)` inside my `User()` class. Also inside a class has many functions, I also have a php file with 2 classes. So how can I access a specific class and a specific function?

Comment: I would suggest you to look at php tutorial for this. In general if a class has a function, calling a function from that class requires you to create that class first and get an object and call a method on it. But do look at some php tutorial on w3schools to help you with that.

Comment: I have a php file that initializes them. First I `require()` them, then initialize them `$user = new User();`. Then I `require()` this file in Registration page that I made. Accessing them will be `$user->functions();`. So in ajax, how can I access them.

Comment: In the ajax where i have written your php script file, is where you should put your php function that accepts a post request. You choose that file and write the path to it there.

Comment: I have a problem. The username is undefined. On the line `$check_username = $_POST['username'];`. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this,

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name = 'signup']").click(function(e) {
        var username = $("input[name = 'username']").val();
        $.ajax ({
            url: "isUserExist_function_existing_file.php", 
            data: { username : username },
            success: function( result ) {
                if(result)
                    alert("Name allready Exist");
                else
                    alert("Name available");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The name of the file is user.php. How can I access the function `isUserExist($username)` of the class `User();`? There are many more functions inside the class, so how can I call the specific function?

Comment: Are you able to access the function like  url: "user/isUserExist",

or Try 

if(isset( $_POST['username'] )) {
     $user = new user();
     $result = $user->isUserNameExist($_POST['username']);
     return $result;
}

Comment: I don't think it will work since the path of the php file is needed. Calling the function inside the class is what I need.

Comment: Ajax should have some endpoint URL that can access public eg:- https://www.facebook.com/chat/user_info/?dpr=1

Are you using any Framework?